# "sysdba" login in Sql Server 2014? Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sysdba

I have a "sysdba" login account among the logins in my SQL Server 2014 instance, and I'm not sure why. I can't do anything with it (change the password, user mappings etc) -- I just a get a "user already exists" error, or the changes just don't take.

I've tried looking this up, but all I can find out is that "sysdba" is an Oracle system privilege, not a username. But Oracle isn't installed on this box. So why is it here?

Comment: Wild guess: Compatiblity. Somebody added it so that some script could run unchanged or with minimal changes.

Comment: Can you drop the login ?
Also make sure you have a sysadmin role login somewhere in case of ;)
By the way, you login with another login ?

Comment: Just to make sure we're not missing anything, can you verify it is a login, not user and it is a SQL login not some integrated auth login?

Comment: @Hybris95 No. I tried, and it just comes right back. We do have a different sysadmin role login.

Comment: @SQLmojoe It's listed under Security --> Logins in SSMS, so my non-DBA self calls that a login. As to it being a SQL login and not some integrated auth login, I think Ben has it right. It's there for somebody's convenience.

Comment: Got any application that handles the security somehow ? Or any automated administration service ?